# How to get (Check Box)checked values from multiple ListView in Android Studio Java?

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to send every checked values from multiple listview to next activity

This is my xml code for List View:

```
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/fdbed"
                        android:layout_width="175dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/ftbed"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="175dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
```

And i want to send every value to next page in button onclicklistener in java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static int m=0;
dualDisplay.setOnClickListener(new OnCli....{
     onClick()
     {
          if(check1.isChecked())
              m++; // you can save this as checked somewhere
          if(check2.isChecked())
              m++; // you can save this as checked somewhere
          if(check3.isChecked())
              m++; // you can save this as checked somewhere
          if(check4.isChecked())
              m++; // you can save this as checked somewhere
     }
});
```

Comment: Yes, isChecked() is a method for checkboxes, if the check box was checked it will return true and if not, It will return false.

Comment: but i don't need true or false

Comment: but now i got some idea and completed my project